# How can I position a background-image an absolute distance from the right of its container?

Tags: css

I can position a small background-image/icon 4 pixels from the center left of its container with:

```
background: url(...) no-repeat 4px 50%;
```

How can I position it 4 pixels from the *right*?

Comment: Perhaps not a duplicate, as two years later, there may be different answers

Comment: The CSS3 spec. document contains all the relevant properties from the previous (CSS2.1) spec. as well the new ones - the `background-position` you linked to is the same as CSS2.1 - i.e. it allows positioning ON the right, but doesn't allow positioning FROM the right inwards.

Comment: No, if you scroll down, it says it allows _four_ specifications. So `background-position: right 10px top 0px;` would position it 10 from the right at the top.

Comment: The *four* specification `background-position` did not work for me on Firefox or IE8. I assume you did not get it to work either?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on your situation and what browsers you want to support, this works (tested on IE7-8, Firefox):

```
background: url(...) no-repeat right 50%; border-right: 4px solid transparent;
```

Of course, if you are already putting a border on the right, this will not help you at all.

*Added on edit:* If the above doesn't work because your are using the border, and you don't care about IE7 (not sure we are quite at that point yet), and your "icon" width is known, then you could do:

```
.yourContainer {
  position: relative;
}

.yourContainer:after {
  content: ' '; 
  display: block; 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  right: 4px; 
  width: 10px; //icon width
  z-index: -1; //makes it act sort of like a background
  background: url(...) no-repeat right 50%;
}
```

Comment: Oh, this is a very nice idea. +1

Answer (score 3):

CSS3 adds a [new way to specify `background-position`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#background-position):

```
background-position: right 10px top 50%;
```

Should position the background-image 10px from the right and vertically centered.

Comment: [Apparently](http://www.standardista.com/css3/css3-background-properties#bg4) supported by FF and Chrome (under the heading mutliple).

Comment: if that works for you, why not!  (possibly provide an IE fallback though.)

Answer (score 2):

how about

```
background: url(...) no-repeat right 50%;
padding:0px;
padding-right:4px;
```

in the case you ever want a border

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't as far as I know.

Popular tricks:

- Adding a 4px transparent margin to the image and giving 
  it `background-position: right`
- Adding a 4px `margin-right` to the element (works in some situations, doesn't in others)
- Using jQuery to determine the element's weight and adjust the image position (yuck!)

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use percentage:

```css
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc {
  background: url("http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/images/sort_asc.png") no-repeat 30% 50%;
}
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc {
  background: url("http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/images/sort_desc.png") no-repeat 30% 50%;
}
table.dataTable thead .sorting {
  background: url("http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/images/sort_both.png") no-repeat 30% 50%;
}
```

Comment: You mean exactly like the other 7 year old answers suggest?