# CSS - Background image positioning

Tags: css, background

Is it possible using CSS `background-position:` to position an image to the far right of an element, but then minus a few pixels so it's not right up against the edge? Without having to add a bit of padding to the actual image itself?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I position a background-image an absolute distance from the right of its container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319514/how-can-i-position-a-background-image-an-absolute-distance-from-the-right-of-its)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets say your div is 1000px wide and you want it 5px from the right the code would be

```
background: url('image.jpg') no-repeat 995px 50%;
```

**Edit:**

As pointed out the code above does not accommodate for the size of the image.

Lets say your div is 1000px wide and your image is 100px wide and you want it 5px from the right the code would be

```
background: url('image.jpg') no-repeat 895px 50%;
```

Your positioning is `Div Size - Image Size - desired spacing from right edge.`

Comment: Yeah I suppose that's one way of doing it, thanks! It would be nice if it could be done relative from the right hand side though, so it can be applied to elements of varying width.

Answer (score 0):

There is some hacky way. Just use background position to the far right:

`background-position: right center;`

and combine it with:

`box-sizing: border-box; border-right: 5px solid transparent;`

for **5px** indentation from the right.